# React Native [TextInput]: How to change scroll position of multiline TextInput?

Tags: react-native

When my multiple InputText started a new line the scroll position will not scroll to bottom automatically resulting texts from new line not be visible. How to make my multiline InputText to autoscroll to the bottom every time a newline created?